# How can I update a UILabel whenever the user state changes?

Tags: swift

I would like to be able to show the user their user state and i have written some code to do so (it is in the viewDidLoad) however it does not up date if the user signs in or signs out.

```swift
import UIKit
import Amplify
import AmplifyPlugins
import AWSMobileClient

class SettingsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let userState = user
    @IBOutlet weak var signInStateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var signOutButton: UIButton!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
            AWSMobileClient.default().initialize { (userState, error) in
                if let userState = userState {
                    self.signInStateLabel.text = " \(userState.rawValue)"
                    print("UserState: \(userState.rawValue)")
                } else if let error = error {
                    print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")

                }
            }

            AWSMobileClient.default().addUserStateListener(self) { (userState, info) in
                switch (userState) {
                    case .guest:
                        print("user is in guest mode.")
                    case .signedOut:
                        print("user signed out")
                    case .signedIn:
                        print("user is signed in.")
                    case .signedOutUserPoolsTokenInvalid:
                        print("need to login again.")
                    case .signedOutFederatedTokensInvalid:
                        print("user logged in via federation, but currently needs new tokens")
                    default:
                        print("unsupported")

                }

            }


    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return 2
    }


    @IBAction func logInPresssed(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "logInSegue", sender: nil)
        signOutButton.isHidden = false
    }
    @IBAction func signOutPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        signOutButton.isHidden = true
        AWSMobileClient.default().signOut()


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this line

```
self.signInStateLabel.text = " \(userState.rawValue)"
```

Inside  of

```
AWSMobileClient.default().addUserStateListener(self) { (userState, info) in  
    self.signInStateLabel.text = " \(userState.rawValue)"
        switch (userState) {
```

Comment: I put it inside of different places inside of "switch" but i keep getting errors.  Could you show me exactly where? Thanks!

Comment: That works kinda but once I sign in the UILabel still says im signed out.